# What i can use if i would like to use 128bit ssl in my login page (php)

Tags: php, ssl

i have got a php login page  which i make use of session . Very simple one.
So if i would like to make it more secure , can it be implement base on php??
As i google i found that ssl is implement on a server (appache?) but not using the php code?

Also, whether have to pay for 128 bit ssl cert? thanks

Comment: yes a ssl cert would make it more secure, and yes you would have to pay for one.

Comment: that's a toolkit not a certificate.

Comment: sorry but are there any free cert resource on the internet i googled some but i would perfer some popular one

Comment: you can create a self singed one for testing purposes, but for real world application you need to pay (not that much)

Comment: You can get a free domain-validated certificate from Startcom - http://www.startcom.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is use the SSL protocol, https. The data stream is encrypted both ways which helps prevent snooping. It uses port 443 and is configured int Apache.

Setting up Apache is not too difficult. You can do a "self-signed" certificate but you will not want to use it in the real world.

Your certificate must be verified by a CA (Certification Authority) They verify that you are a legitimate site. That is what you pay for when you buy a certificate.

However, if you don't care about that the self-signed certificate will still encrypt your data. The problem is that any visitor that comes to your site will get a nasty, "this is an untrusted site" message and very few people will go past that page.

I've found the easiest way to setup a dev. box is to download XAMPP.

Comment: so , nothing to do with php??
entirely need to config appache only?thanks

Comment: Yes, it's all Apache. However in PHP you do need to make sure to validate your incoming variables ($_GET & $_POST). Use Regexp to strip unwanted characters and when accessing the database use the mysql_prepare() method, or equivalent *_prepare() for you RDBMS.